# Whether the graph of rational map is closed

Tags: algebraic-geometry, rational-functions

$X,Y$ is irreducible affine or projective variety, $\phi:X\to Y$ be a rational map, and let $U\subset X$ be the open set of regular point of $\phi$. The graph $\Gamma_\phi$ is defined as the closure of $\{(x,\phi(x)):x\in U\}$.

If $Y$ is affine variety, can we have $\Gamma_\phi=\{(x,\phi(x)):x\in U\}$, i.e. the set is closed?

In general, is there any sufficient and necessary condition to state that $\{(x,\phi(x)):x\in U\}\subset X\times Y$ is a closed set?

Comment: Having $Y$ separated and $\phi$ a morphism will do it.

Comment: @BenP. What kind of morphism, I don't want the regular map.

Comment: Now I think of it, I don't think we need $\phi$ as a morphism (defined globally) since the graph of $\phi$ and $\phi|_{U}$ are the same and we can apply the proof I'm thinking of to $\phi|_{U}$ the proof I'm thinking of relies on continuity of the map in question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\mathbb{A}^1$ and $Y=X-\{0\}$. Then $Y$ is open in $X$ and the identity map $Y\to Y$ gives a rational map (not defined at $0$) $X\to Y$. Then you can easily check that the graph as you describe is closed.

Comment: But I want to show that "all" rational phi will be closed, not just one.

Comment: @yaoliding I misunderstood. No, for many rational $\phi$, the graph will not be closed. Try the rational map $\mathbb{P}^2\to \mathbb{P}^1$, given by $(x,y,z)\mapsto (y,z)$. It is not defined at $P=(1,0,0)$ and the graph of $\mathbb{P}^2-\{P\}\to \mathbb{P}^1$ is not closed in $\mathbb{P}^2\times\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want Y to be affine, to see whether phi must be closed on affine space

Comment: @yaoliding No, let $Y=\mathbb{A}^1$ and $X$ the rational curve with a cusp $P$, so that you have a finite birational morphism $Y\to X$. Let $f$ be its inverse. Then, $f$ is defined on $X-\{P\}$ and you can check that the graph of $f$ in $X-\{P\}\times Y$ is not closed in $X\times Y$.

Comment: I don't know how to prove that, but I'll think about it for a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's take $Y$ separated, this means that the set $\Delta(Y)=\{(y,y)|\ y\in Y\}$ is closed in $Y\times Y$.

Now we consider the map $\phi|_{U}\times id_{Y}: U\times Y\rightarrow Y\times Y,\ (x,y)\mapsto (\phi|_{U}(x),y)$.

Since $\phi$ is a rational map $\phi|_{U}$ is continuous and hence so is $\phi|_{U}\times id_{Y}$.

$(\phi|_{U}\times id_{Y})^{-1}(\Delta(Y))=\{(x,y)\in U\times Y|\ (\phi|_{U}(x),y)=(y,y)\}=\{(x,\phi|_{U}(x)|\ x\in U\}=\Gamma_{\phi}$

By continuity the preimage of a closed set is closed, and since $Y$ is separated that means that $\Gamma_{\phi}$ is closed in $X\times Y$

Comment: This proves $\Gamma_\phi$ is closed as a subset of $U\times Y$, but not that it is closed as a subset of $X\times Y$.

Comment: I knew there was a reason I needed $\phi$ defined everywhere, i.e. a morphism. Missed the obvious. Thanks.

Comment: But if phi is regular map, the consequence is trivial. What I really care is whether the rational map is "bounded" near the singularity.

Comment: What do you mean by "bounded"?

Comment: Say f:C to C is a meromorphic function. So all its singularities are poles, not essential singularity. And near the singularity, the value of f tends to infinity, no accumulate to the finity value (but for essential singularity, subsequence of f(z) can converge to almost all value). So the graph of f doesn't need to take a closure.